# Replace WinXP taskbar Tooltip for another program

Tags: winapi, tooltip, taskbar, windows-xp

I need to replace the common Tooltip from WinXP taskbar for another application.
So, I need to run an application when the mouse hover a task button. Is this possible, programatically?
If so, how?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to mess with another application, without that application being architected to support such messing? Without knowing further details, it sounds like you're trying to do something you shouldn't be.

Comment: I don't know if the taskbar has been architectured to do such a "mess". That's why I'm asking this question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, everything is always possible (RPM or other, see Google Groups for samples in C , Win32)